# How to minimise the risk of using a MacBook Pro 2015 recalled due to battery faults

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

My MacBook 2015 pro Retina 15'' has to be recalled by Apple. The reason is that its battery may be a fire hazard; [eg macromors](https://www.macrumors.com/2019/07/03/macbook-pro-battery-recall-program-damage/). Apple said the repairs can take two-three weeks. Because of my work, I absolutely can't have this interruption during the next month. (I will get the MBP fixed in a month's time.)

**Question:** If I must use my MBP, how can I minimise the battery risks?

I plan to do these:

- Shut down and unplug when not using
- Have a CO2 fire extinguisher nearby
- Only use the MBP plugged in to the mains, and not from the battery
- Constantly monitor the fan speeds and the battery/CPU temperatures and shut down when they spike

Would these work?  Or should I do something else instead or in addition?

Comment: Apple says don’t use it on the link you yourself provide, so why do you think we will tell you different?

Comment: Bear in mind that your laptop catching fire will be an interruption to your work.

Comment: @SolarMike Apple might have various commercial reasons for their advice, which may not matter to me or to  SE contributors. E.g., Apple may seek to avoid  bad publicity from a few laptop fires. As they sell millions of laptops, this makes sense to them, even if the probability  of an individual laptop burning is tiny. Maybe Apple would want people buy new laptops, and so on.

Comment: @benwiggy Very true! That's why I try to reduce the probability of this fire. Also, such a fire would fall under "force majeur" in my work contract. Then I can use my insurance to buy a new laptop quicker than three weeks.

Comment: Actually, maybe I should talk to my business insurer! Thanks @benwiggy

Comment: @Tupolev._ If your laptop does catch fire due to a known defect, then I think you would have a case to get a new one free from Apple, rather than having to purchase one yourself or rely on insurance.

Comment: But if you ignore the advice given ie don’t use it then they may claim it’s your own stupidity for the loss and not replace it...

Comment: @SolarMike  Except I  never received any messages from Apple about the recall, but found out about this by accident. Also, I'm not asking about replacement eligibility, but about  decreasing the risk of using it for the month when I can't do without a laptop.

Comment: Except you have now read, and understood, the notification so as they often say “ignorance is no defense”...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimizing the risk is simple. Don’t charge the battery.

Does’t matter if you are sleeping or shut down, the discharge doesn’t trigger a problem. The charging does. So just don’t use the Mac once it needs a charge.

In case you're worried about the time to fix - here is a crowd-sourced list of times to repair:

Battery Recall Turnaround by Apple*:

```
From            | to Depot     | Turnaround  | Notes 
London, UK      | Prague, CZ   | 2-3 weeks   | Estimate by Apple, 31 Aug 19
Minneapolis, MN | Memphis, TN  | 2 days      | Apple quoted 2 weeks
```

*feel free to update.

As for repair times, it would be good to specify where you will be shipping the MacBook and where the repair parts might be stocked. Just because the US might have ample stock, other countries might need the whole 2 weeks to ship and perform the repairs.

The rest of the timing is for US based repairs: I would say two weeks is much longer than we’re seeing in the US. We sent two last week for work and the box with the fixed Mac was delivered three days after the box was shipped. (So it was our of our hands for two days only.) Some repairs have taken us a week, but that’s the exception of the 25 or so we’ve sent in already.

Also, you will almost certainly see the case swell before any charge causes a fire in most cases so look for that as well.

As for putting out a LiPo battery fire, CO2 is a less good choice than water or sand. The battery has so much energy and generates it’s own oxygen so smothering it for a short time and cooling it a little with CO2 might not be effective. Of course use it if you have it, but go get a bucket of something or a shovel to lift and move the MacBook to a safer place where the fire won’t spread (concrete floor, outside, etc...)

Comment: That's exactly the info I needed! Just to confirm: my safest bet is to always have my Mac plugged in the mains, and the battery at a 100% charge? (I only use my Mac near electric sockets.)

Comment: You're lucky in the US. From the UK, MacBooks are sent to Prague by train or road, so replacement can take up to three weeks.

Comment: @Tupolev._ I’m so happy you realized my data was very selective. Would you mind editing in a little matrix so we can crowd source where the depots are and what turnaround might be expected?

Comment: Done. Hopefully that's the right format. Please feel free to edit.

Comment: Oh - @Tupolev._ let’s put that in an answer. If you want to start a new answer that’s awesome or you can edit into mine. People are very hesitant to edit a question body, answers they will update regularly in my experience. The format is PERFECT